# Application of teachings of Mahabharata

Tags: mahabharata, book-recommendation

Is there any good book on Mahabharata which explains the psychology behind the stories with real life lessons ?
Thanks

Comment: You can try Bhagvat Geeta initially.

Comment: Try [Yuganta: The End of an Epoch by Irawati Karve](https://www.amazon.com/Yuganta-End-Epoch-Irawati-Karve/dp/8125032282). See review [here](http://creative.sulekha.com/yuganta-by-irawati-karve-a-book-review_219079_blog).

Answer (score 1):

It will vary by tradition but I would recommend Sanyal Mahasay's Gita. It breaks down the symbolism of the different Mahabharat characters and what they represent within each sadhaka. The "real life lessons" are taught through sadhana that needs to be learned from Guru.

His Gita is available in Hindi-
http://indianmind.co.in/books/srimadbhagavadgita-3-vols-in-hindi

Also in English (but Hindi version is better if you can read)-
https://www.abebooks.com/Spiritual-Gita-3-Vols-Set-Shyamacharan-Lahiris/209683059/bd